# generate line automatically in urls (django)

Tags: python, django, url, path

I would like to know how to create a row in the `urlpatterns` array automatically from the forms file.

In the forms file we have:

```
phone = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Phone.objects.all())
```

Then we will create in urls this line :

```
path('phone', views.phone, name='phone')
```

Comment: How do you plan to write the logic of `views.phone` ?

Comment: I will only retrieve a phone number with an ajax request and return the person who has this number